# Convert BTC to BCC from Bitcoin Core Wallet

Tags: wallet

Not sure if this is the proper forum for this question but I was wondering, what is the easiest way to experiment with converting BTC into BCC? Suppose I have a BTC core wallet which holds 1 BTC but I only want to claim 0.10 worth BTC as BCC?  From what I understand, the way to do this is would be to create another BTC wallet, transfer 0.90 BTC into the new wallet, and then import the private key of the original BTC wallet into a BCC wallet.   This way the remainder of 0.10 BTC will transfer over to BCC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transfer all your BTC to the new BTC wallet, after that you import the private keys from old BTC wallet into a BCC wallet and you will have the same amount of BCC. From here on you can decide with how much BCC you want to play with (you cannot clam partial amounts of BCC)